# Timescale DB Create distributed hypertable

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, timescaledb, postgresql-13

I want to create a PoC of a distributed hypertable, using TimescaleDB and docker compose.

I've set up a docker compose with two instances and created the respective table in both instances.

Let's say instance A is the access node (main node)
Before executing the query `SELECT create_distributed_hypertable('sensor_data', 'time', 'sensor_id');`, I added the other data node successfully by running: `SELECT add_data_node('australia-node', host => 'au-db', password => 'XXXXX', database => 'XXXXX');`

Also, by querying `SELECT * FROM timescaledb_information.data_nodes;`, the australia-node is the only entry in this view, meaning that it is recgonized by the access node

When I try to run `SELECT create_distributed_hypertable('sensor_data', 'time', 'sensor_id');`, I receive the folllowing error:

`SQL Error [08001]: ERROR: could not connect to "australia-node"   Detail: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Note: I execute all the queries, using DBeaver SQL editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your instances are up and running, you need to configure authentication so that data nodes accept connections from access node. This is what we refer as Multi-node authentication.

Since it is a PoC, go for Trust authentication which trusts all incoming connections and then create distributed hypertable

Reference: https://docs.timescale.com/self-hosted/latest/multinode-timescaledb/multinode-auth/

Comment: This was very helpful. Indeed this partially resolves my issue. In particular, I am able to create the distributed hypertable by following the steps in the link you provided. Thanks for the answer!!!